# Как через CSS изменить толщину границ ячеек в таблице QTableView?

Tags: css, qt

Использую программу от сименса для построения SCADA-систем (`WinCC OA`), которая построена на `Qt`. Напрямую, с библиотекой `Qt` в ней работать нельзя, но можно изменять отображение графических объектов, используя `CSS`.
Мне нужно изменить толщину границ ячеек (линий между ячейками). Как менять цвет границ ячеек, я нашёл, а вот, как менять толщину - нигде не могу найти.
Также я нашёл, как менять ширину внешней границы таблицы, но вот как менять ширину границ ячеек!?

Вот пример моего кода для настройки границ таблицы:

```
QTableView[type = "myTable"] {
  border-style : Solid;
  border-color : #CCCCCC;
  border-width : 2px;
  gridline-color: #CCCCCC; 
}
```

Comment: Напишите в вопросе, пожалуйста, как цвет границ ячеек менять

Comment: @gil9red  добавил. Последняя строчка как раз изменяет цвет  границ.

Answer (score 1):

Одно из решений следующее (работает в QSS Editor):

```
QTableWidget::item {
 border: 5px solid #CCCCCC;
}

QTableWidget::item {
 border-right: 5px solid #CCCCCC;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Но в WinCC OA это вообще никак не работает. Даже частично не работает. Так что, может быть есть ещё какое-то решение.

Comment: Эх, это оказалось не решением. Это меняет область внутри самих ячеек таблицы. Границы не затрагивает.